# Tool to clip segments of a video

Tags: video, software, editing, video-editor, software-recommendation

newbie here,

I want to remove some segments of an MP4 video I have. Which easy to use tool would you recommend. Preferably free.

I'm using Windows.

Comment: Including the OS you are using is always useful information.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: You're right. Just added.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try this one for example:

http://www.dvdvideomedia.com/video-cutter-joiner/video-cutter-joiner.html

But as will all "free" software, be aware during installation if you need to opt-in or out of any added software, tool-bars and so forth.

Comment: This most likely yet another of hundreds of similar programs from the same group in China that violates the (L)GPL.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to extract sections. You can do this with ffmpeg which is multiplatform, open source, and free. This example will skip the first 12 seconds and create an output that is 10 seconds long. The video and audio will be copied instead of re-encoded, so there will be no quality loss.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 12 -t 00:00:10.00 -c copy -map 0 output.mp4
```

What these options mean:

- `-ss` Offset time, or how much to skip. Value can be in seconds, or hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds.
- `-t` Output duration. Value can be in seconds, or hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds.
- `-c copy -map 0` Copy all input streams to the output.

Windows users can get FFmpeg from [Zeranoe FFmpeg Builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). See the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page if you're using Linux or OS X for several options.